# how to change attached PSN account on PS Vita

Tags: ps-vita

I got this used PS Vita, and the account is still on it, and I need to sign into the account to deactivate it, is there anyway to get rid of the account through factory reset or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this recently, so apologies if it's changed at all, but you can go into settings and choose to "format" and then "restore" the system - which wipes the account off of it, so you can log in as yourself.